# How to get a key value errors response if validator fails in laravel

Tags: laravel, validation

I am using Laravel 7 and I am doing an API project. I would like to obtain a key value errors response if validator fails.

This is my code in the child controller:

```
    $rules = array(
        'source' => 'required',
        'customerId' => 'required|integer',
        'statusCode' => 'exists:status,status_name',
        'requestType' => 'exists:request_types,variable',
        'login' => '',
        'yearCreationDate' => 'digits:4|integer|min:1900|max:'.(date('Y')+1),
        'assistanceRequestIds.*' => 'integer',
        'variationId' => 'integer',
    ); 

    $validator = Validator::make( $request->all(), $rules );

    if ( $validator->fails() ) 
    {
        return parent::return_failed_response('Bad Request', $validator->errors()->all(), '400');
    }
```

This is the function called in the parent controller:

```
protected function return_failed_response ($code, $description, $header)
{

    $return_data = array (
        "code" => $code,
        "description" => $description,
    );

    return response()->json($return_data, $header)->header('Code', $header);
}
```

Unfortunately the response that I received from the validator has the following json format:

```
{

    "code": "Bad Request",
    "description": [
        "The source field is required",
        "The customer id field is required."
    ]
}
```

But I would like to receive a response in the following json format:

```
{
    "code": "Bad Request",
    "description": {
        "source": [
            "The source field is required"
        ],
        "customerId": [
            "The customer id field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

Is it possible to obtain a similar response from the validator of Laravel? Can help?

Comment: Don't you think you can write your own response array and just return it?

Comment: Could you show me an example?

Comment: Read these topics. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#specifying-a-custom-message-for-a-given-attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`all()`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Support/MessageBag.html#method_all) of the MessageBag object only returns all occured error messages but not their related keys. Use [`toArray`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Support/MessageBag.html#method_toArray) instead:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return parent::return_failed_response('Bad Request',
        $validator->errors()->toArray(), 400);
}
```

Available aliases for this method are `messages()` or `getMessages()`.

Comment: Ok perfect solution!

Answer (score 1):

If you `dd($validator->errors())` you will see

```
Illuminate\Support\MessageBag {#3535 ▼
  #messages: array:1 [▶]
  #format: ":message"
}
```

What you need to get is `messages` which can be accessed by `$validator->errors()->messages()`